# How to add an item to an ExtJS GridPanel without firing selectionchanged event

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs, gridpanel

I've got an ExtJS interface that addresses a problem I'm sure *tons* of people have had before.  I have a service that exposes a list of items, and I need to show that list in a GridPanel.  I have this part working.  When I click one of the items, I handle the `selectionchange` event in the GridPanel's SelectionModel, and use it to load details of the resource from another REST call.

Now, I want to be able to *add* a new item.  This seems like it should be simple, but I want to add the item to the GridPanel and at the same time clear the "detail" fields so the user can enter new details and save a complete item.  I have an Add button, which creates a Prompt to input an item name.

Now, I add this item to the GridPanel's backing data store (a `JsonStore` if that matters) and use `getSelectionModel().selectLastRow()` to highlight it.  Of course, this fires off the `selectionchange` event, which wants to load the details of the (non-existent) item.  I've tried using `.purgeListeners()`, making the `selectLastRow() call, then restoring the selectionchange listener, but for some reason the changed event still fires off -- I don't actually have any symptoms in the UI, but I can see in Firebug that it's making a (failed) GET call for the item details.

I'd like to stop this from happening, and I feel like this should be a common / easy problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution.  What's the *right* way to add a new item to the GridPanel without having your code try to "look up" the item before you save it?

ETA: A commenter pointed out that there's a `phantom` property on Record objects, which sounds like exactly what a want.  However, when I load my item list as

```
STORE = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
  autoLoad: true,
  url: 'items'
  method: 'GET',
  storeId: 'store',
  root: 'list',
  remoteSort: false,
  fields: ['name']
});
```

*all* the records in the list, as soon as I load them, are marked `phantom`.  Does `phantom` not work with JsonStore?  Should I go about this another way?

ETA Again: OK, found it.  I wasn't setting the `idProperty` property on my JsonStore constructor, which meant that the Records didn't have an id, which meant that they were always `phantom`.  Now my new record shows `phantom` while ones that are already in the DB do not.  Woo-hoo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to do this without messing with the event chain or handlers that I have already setup.

One easy way seems along the lines of - "somehow **figure out** in the selectionchange listener whether record that was selected is a persistent one or not (yet)"

The "figuring out" part can be achieved by checking [record](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.Record).phantom as suggested by Kevin in comments below

Comment: +1, but you don't have to implement the tracking. It is already available as record.phantom which is bool true unless the record was created by the reader.

Comment: Kevin, if you made that full-on answer I'd accept it.  That's *exactly* what I had hoped to find.